# Programmatically adding UIImage into collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is my custom class for the collection view cell:

```
import UIKit

class NavBarCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var avatarImageView: UIImageView = {
        var avatarView = UIImageView()
        avatarView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        return avatarView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        avatarImageView = UIImageView()
        contentView.addSubview(avatarImageView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` of my controller I have

```
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    navBarCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    navBarCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    navBarCollectionView.register(NavBarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    navBarCollectionView.delegate = self
    navBarCollectionView.dataSource = self
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(navBarCollectionView)
    navBarCollectionView.reloadData()
```

And in `cellForItem` I have:

```
        let navBarCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)) as! NavBarCell

        var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "TestImage")!
        navBarCell.avatarImageView.image = image
        navBarCell.avatarImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        navBarCell.avatarImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.getRandomColor().cgColor
        navBarCell.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        return navBarCell
```

But the image views are not showing up. If I add `navBarCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` then the cells show up, but not the images.

Anything I'm missing, or not implementing correctly?

Comment: You need to set `avatarImageView`'s frame at initialize. If you want the imageView to scale to cell's frame either reset frame at `cellForItem` or use constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCell` is already a view, you can add `avatarImageView` directly to it:

```
addSubview(avatarImageView)
```

You can also set the constraints, for example:

```
avatarImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
avatarImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
avatarImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
avatarImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
avatarImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't realize you could directly add the subview. All is well now thanks again!

Comment: This isn't quite right. You should add the image view to the cell's `contentView`, not to the cell itself, just as is being done in the question's code.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be that you create a prototype cell and add your image view in the interface builder. In this specific scenario, I believe that the error is that you're not setting the frame for your image view to scale to your cell frame.

Try printing out the frame of your image view, it will probably show 0,0,0,0.